# Is it possible to have all the adapter configuration in one file in IBM MFP

Tags: maven, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using JavaScript HttpAdapter in my maven project. I have a situation where my customer expects to have more than one HttpAdapter as part of the adapter.xml file. This is something that I have not tried before.

Is it possible to have more than one adapter configuration in a single file? Does IBM MFP adapter support this?

If yes, please share your thoughts.

Thanks,
Janarthanan

Answer (score 2):

> my customer expects to have more than one HttpAdapter as part of the
>   adapter.xml file.

**You can't have an adapter.xml file for more than one adapter.**

An **Adapter** is a separate Maven project.   You can create one adapter with multiple **Procedure**.

> Is it possible to have more than one adapter configuration in a single
>   file?

If you are creating multiple adapter in a project then you can put all adapter in a one file. 
[image]

Also you can build & deploy all adapter from project root folder using these command:

```
mfpdev adapter build all
mfpdev adapter deploy all
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean here by a "single file".  You can't have an adapter.xml file for more than adapter.  Do you mean single project?

Comment: @JohnGerken correct. here i mean to say that keep all adapters ( maven project) in one file. see the updated answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Gaurab Kumar - Thanks for your reply, will check it out and get back to you.

Comment: Usually 'adapters' folder should contain a main pom.xml that will act as a main project file for all adapters.
You add your adapters in main pom.xml into the <modules>..</modules> section.