# Grouping Adapters in a Single Maven Project

Tags: maven, ibm-mobilefirst, jax-rs, mobilefirst-adapters

I found a solution to grouping adapters into a single maven project (project is on IBM Mobile First), [here is this tutorial.](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/creating-adapters/#grouping-adapters-in-a-single-maven-project)

And now I have question about it. I created a root folder and there is a second step `2.Put the Maven adapter projects in it.` So what I need to put in it? I'm a little bit confused because I'm just started learning how to work with Maven (I worked before with Gradle).

//Edit: This answer isn't that what could save my day. I now that I can group all adapters into one maven project, but when I just copy and paste my adapters into some other folder, create a pom.xml file and finally build with `mfpdev adapter build` it's give my just error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have all the adapter configuration in one file in IBM MFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795564/is-it-possible-to-have-all-the-adapter-configuration-in-one-file-in-ibm-mfp)

Comment: Use mfpdev adapter build all

Answer (score 1):

Each MFP adapter project is a maven project. The step talks about placing your individual adapter projects under a single root project folder.The root project's pom contains references to the sub maven projects( individual adapter projects). Now, when the root maven project executes, it executes the sub projects ( individual adapter projects).

Comment: I have already seven adapters created, so I should just "paste" and "copy" then into some other folder?

Comment: Yes, as @Vivin told, Each MFP adapter project is a maven project. You can copy & paste all adapter project in one folder.

Comment: @chebad, did you copy the maven project folder? Or only the files ( from adapter projects), into the root project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the steps for creating single adapters and place these created adapter projects inside the root folder.